# Unable to retrieve the changeCounts properties for a git Pull Request in AzureDevOps using the REST api

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I am trying to find (roughly) the number of lines of code that has been changed in a Pull Request using the Azure DevOps REST Api. The documentation suggests that it is possible but I have been unable to get it to work.

The api's return a GitCommitRef[] as a response and inside the GitCommitRef there is a changeCounts property, but this mostly appears to be missing from most responses.

Things I have tried\observed:

**1. List of commits for a pull request**
I can get a list of the commits for a pull request, but this does not include the changeCounts

Request

> https://{{coreServer}}/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/git/repositories/{{repositoryId}}/pullRequests/{{pullRequestId}}/commits?api-version=6.0

Response

```
{
"count": 3,
"value": [
    {
        "commitId": "0b415...669fda",
        "author": {
            "name": "name",
            "email": "name@email.com",
            "date": "2021-11-02T03:34:23Z"
        },
        "committer": {
            "name": "name",
            "email": "name@email.com",
            "date": "2021-11-02T03:34:23Z"
        },
        "comment": "checkin commit",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/git/repositories/5f32ff...2a97ac1/commits/0b415...669fda"
    },
```

**2. Getting a list of commits for a repository does return the changeCounts**
So I thought, okay I will just retrieve each commit and get the counts that way, but I cannot get it to honour the searchCriteria, so if I ask for a specific commit I still get all the commits on the repo

> https://{{coreServer}}/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/git/repositories/{{repositoryId}}/commits?searchCriteria.compareVersion.version=67...4b4&searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionType=commit&api-version=6.0

Response

```
{
"count": 100,
"value": [
    {
        "commitId": "71...a93a",
        "author": {
            "name": "name",
            "email": "name@email.com",
            "date": "2021-11-07T23:59:52Z"
        },
        "committer": {
            "name": "name",
            "email": "name@email.com",
            "date": "2021-11-07T23:59:52Z"
        },
        "comment": "Merged PR 11087: did some work",
        "commentTruncated": true,
        "changeCounts": {
            "Add": 0,
            "Edit": 1,
            "Delete": 0
        },
```

**3. Specifying the commit id does not return the changeCounts either**
If I specify the commit id when retrieving a commit that, only returns the commit but not the changeCounts

> https://{{coreServer}}/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/git/repositories/{{repositoryId}}/commits?searchCriteria.ids=0b...fda&api-version=6.0

Response

```
{
"count": 1,
"value": [
    {
        "commitId": "0b...da",
        "author": {
            "name": "name",
            "email": "name@email.com",
            "date": "2021-11-02T03:34:23Z"
        },
        "committer": {
            "name": "name",
            "email": "name@email.com",
            "date": "2021-11-02T03:34:23Z"
        },
        "comment": "did some work",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/git/repositories/5f...ac1/commits/0b...da"
    }
]
```

}

Anyone have an idea why the api's do not seem to be working for me?